# mix two columns values row by row separated by comma in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLRzs.png)I have 2 columns and I want the values inside the columns to be in single column for row by row separated by comma. The desired output is :

col1
1
2
3
4
5

col2
6
7
8
9
10

output
1,6
2,7
3,8
4,9
5,10

Comment: As illustrated by your example, Col1 is a row containing 1,2,3,4,5 and Col2 is a row containing 6,7,8,9,10.  Is this what you want or are you looking for something different.  What have you tried?  Please provide a complete [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") containing both data, and code that can be copied and pasted along with a clear description of what is wrong with your current effort.

Comment: Screen Shot 2022-04-29 at 3.58.39 PM

Comment: they are columns not rows. I want the values of the 2 columns be in a single column next to the other 2 columns. I want them to be merged row by row. I don't want them to be joined